# How to Save Excel Worksheet as PDF with Command Button?

Tags: vba

I am getting a 'Syntax Error' with the coding beneath the Next R line toward the bottom below.  I am trying to save the open worksheet as a PDF file referencing the order number found in cell D3.  Thanks for your help!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim OrderDate As String, PONumber As String, Vendor As String, ShipTo As String, SKU As String, Path As String, filename As String
Dim R As Long, LastSKURow As Long, NextDBRow As Long, OFrm As Worksheet, DB As Worksheet
Set OFrm = Worksheets("Order Form 1")
Set DB = Worksheets("Database")
OrderDate = OFrm.Range("B3")
PONumber = OFrm.Range("D3")
Vendor = OFrm.Range("B7")
ShipTo = OFrm.Range("D7")
LastSKURow = OFrm.Cells(OFrm.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
For R = 3 To LastSKURow
    SKU = OFrm.Range("F" & R).Value
    NextDBRow = DB.Cells(DB.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    DB.Range("A" & NextDBRow).Value = OrderDate
    DB.Range("B" & NextDBRow).Value = PONumber
    DB.Range("C" & NextDBRow).Value = Vendor
    DB.Range("D" & NextDBRow).Value = ShipTo
    DB.Range("E" & NextDBRow).Value = SKU
Next R
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
OFrm.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Path ="C:\PDF\"
        filename = OFrm.Range("D3")
        OpenAfterPublish = False
OFRrm.SaveAs filename:=Path & filename & ".pdf", FileFormat:=xlTypePDF
End Sub
```

Comment: filename = OFrm.Range("D3").value

Comment: Stijll getting a syntax error for line beginning with OFrm.SaveAs...

Comment: You may need to check the value of D3 and how that path+filename+.pdf looks after it is built.  Could be problems with too many \'s or not enough.

Answer (score 1):

The SaveAs line is redundant. You just need to fix the ExportAsFixedFormat to work properly. When using named parameters, you need to use := instead of just =. I recommend creating a new Sub for the PDF save.

```
Sub SaveOrderAsPDF()
    Dim PDFName As String
    PDFName = Worksheets("Order Form 1").Range("D3").Value
    ChDir "C:\PDF"
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\PDF\" & PDFName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:= _
    True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
End Sub
```

With that working, just add SaveOrderAsPDF to your existing sub.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your variable "filename" is conflicting with the method keyword "Filename". Call your variable something else...

```
OFRrm.SaveAs Filename:= Path & myFile & ".pdf", FileFormat:=xlTypePDF
```

or just eliminate the keywords in the arguments altogether:

```
OFRrm.SaveAs Path & myFile & ".pdf", xlTypePDF
```